# i want to show a home page in dashboard if other options is not clicked

Tags: php

i want to show total records in a database in dashboard-home.php .

> i am getting error of undefined index

[image: here is the image]

how to make proper links to pages to get contents in a same page i mean different pages in a same div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SIS Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<body id="dashbody">
    <div class="row dashboard-head">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-2">  
                    <a href="dashboard.php?dash-home"><h2>DASHBOARD</h2></a>
                </div>      
                <div class="tpad navbar-right">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p><b><?php echo "Welcome  "  .$_SESSION['user']; ?></b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 logout-a">
                        <a href="logout.php?logout" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Logout</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row db-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-md-3 left-panel">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="dashboard.php?page=user">User Panel</a></li>
                                - <a href="dashboard.php?page=view_users">View Users</a><hr>
                            <li><a href="dashboard.php?page=gallery">Gallery Panel</a></li>
                                - <a href="dashboard.php?page=view_gallery">View Gallery</a><hr>
                            <li><a href="dashboard.php?news">News Panel</a></li>
                                - <a href="dashboard.php?view_news">View All News</a><hr>
                            <li><a href="dashboard.php?page=events">Events Panel</a></li>
                                - <a href="dashboard.php?page=view_events">View Events</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 right-panel">

                        <?php 

                            if($_GET['dash-home']){
                                include'dashboard-home.php';
                            }

                            if(isset($_GET['gallery'])){
                                include'pages/gallery_panel.php';
                            }
                            if(isset($_GET['news'])){
                                include'news_panel.php';
                            }
                            if(isset($_GET['view_news'])){
                                include'view_news.php';
                            }
                            if(isset($_GET['edit_news'])){
                                include'edit_news.php';
                            }


                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` needs `session_start()` at top level, u r using isset() for all $_GET variable but not using here: `$_GET['dash-home']`

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Note that, your URL is **dashboard.php**, no query string with `dashboard.php?dash-home=1`, it means this condition can't be work and you will get the Undefined Index notice as you are getting:

```
if($_GET['dash-home']){
```

And if you check your code you are already using `isset()` for other input so you need to add `isset()` here also:

```
if(isset($_GET['dash-home'])){
```

**As per your dashboard link:**

```
<a href="dashboard.php?dash-home"><h2>DASHBOARD</h2></a>
```

You can't get the value from `dash-home` because you didn't use value of `dash-home`, you can use like:

```
<a href="dashboard.php?dash-home=1"><h2>DASHBOARD</h2></a>
```

*One more important point, `$_SESSION` needs `session_start()` at top level and i didn't find this function in your file. This is just side note, you need to take care of this.*

**Update:**
If you want to display an included file in default than you need to use else part and as per your comment you need to use one include file as per condition, try this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['dash-home'])){
    include 'dashboard-home.php';
}
elseif(isset($_GET['gallery'])){
    include 'pages/gallery_panel.php';
}
elseif(isset($_GET['news'])){
    include 'news_panel.php';
}
elseif(isset($_GET['view_news'])){
    include 'view_news.php';
}
elseif(isset($_GET['edit_news'])){
    include 'edit_news.php';
}
else{
    include 'dashboard-home.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: when i login in dashboard i want to show something in  <div class="col-md-9 right-panel"> and these are the option if(isset($_GET['gallery'])){
                                include'pages/gallery_panel.php';
                            }
                            if(isset($_GET['news'])){
                                include'news_panel.php';
                            }
                             if clicked will show that page in col-md-9 div but what i mean to say is i want to show on dashboard home if nothing is clicked on default and i have used session at top

Comment: @SureshBakhadyo: u want to view only include file?? or all?

Comment: i want to view include file

Comment: @SureshBakhadyo: note that, include file based on your url, now what file do u want to include when just hit this url `yoururl/dashboard.php`

Comment: @SureshBakhadyo: i am asking, which file do you want to show on `dashboard.php` ? and do u want to use all include file?

Comment: sir do u have skype coz i want to show you in  the skype by sharing the screens

Comment: @SureshBakhadyo: first check the update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend to use switch instead of if-else
2. You are checking for $_GET['dash-home'] but you need to check for $_GET['page']

Try:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        switch ($_GET['page'])
        {
            case 'dash-home':
                include 'dashboard-home.php';
                break;
            case 'gallery':
                include 'pages/gallery_panel.php';
                break;

            and so on.....
        }
    }
```